# Evaluating global variable within a module

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions

I'm trying to work with something like the following:

```
a = b;
f[x_, b_] := Module[{N},
  N = Abs[a];
  10 N
  ]
f[1, 1]
```

The output of running this is:

```
10 Abs[b]
```

What I'm trying to do is have the Module use the input value of b to evaluate a, so that the output in this case would be just 10. I know that two possible solutions would be to write either:

```
a[b_] = b;
f[x_, b_] := Module[{N},
  N = Abs[a[b]];
  10 N
  ]
f[1, 1]
```

or:

```
f[x_, b_] := Module[{N,a},
  a = b;
  N = Abs[a];
  10 N
  ]
f[1, 1]
```

Either of these second two solve the problem, however in reality I have a whole list of variables already defined like "a" outside the modules, and a whole list of modules they are called. I am just trying to find out if there's a way of using something closer to the first piece of code to do this, to minimise changes to the existing code.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a built-in symbol with a specific meaning.

Comment: You are assuming that the function argument `b` is a local variable that has a value. That is true in some languages, like C. It is not true in Mathematica. The argument is literally applied into the right-hand-side of the `:=`-definition. It is not a variable.

Comment: I also don't fully understand the requirement, but something may be possible with `Block`. `f[b0_] := Block[{b = b0}, ...]`. `Block` will temporarily set the value of the *global* `b` to `b0`. Be careful with such hacks, they can come back to bite you!